# At change reset and making readonly to false with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a bunch of fields.

There is an `application` field which has two values `registration and renewal`.

If a user selects `renewal` then other fields will be filled up and make the fields readonly. If the user then selects `registration` all the fields will be reset and make the readonly false. I am able to reset the form but can't make the `readonly` false.

here is my code :

```
var form = $('form');
form.trigger("reset");
form.prop("readonly",false);
```

p.s. Obviously I can change the readonly to false one by one by selector. I'm looking for a solution if there are any ways to change at once

Comment: You need to set `prop('readonly', false)` on the child `input` elements within the form, not the `form` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the inputs

```
$('form')
  .trigger("reset")
  .find(":input").prop("readonly", false)
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btn").on("click", function() {
    $('form')
    .trigger("reset")
    .find(":input").prop("readonly", false) 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" readonly value="Initial value" />
  <textarea readonly>Initial value</textarea>
  <select>
    <option selected value="">Initial value</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
  </select>

  <button type="button" id="btn">Reset and remove readonly</button>
</form>
```

> The [.removeProp()](https://api.jquery.com/removeprop/) method removes properties set by the .prop() method.
>
> Note:This method should not be used to remove built-in (native)
> properties such as "checked", "disabled", "selected", or others. This
> can lead to unexpected behavior.
>
> It's almost always better to use .prop() to set native properties to
> false instead of removing them.

Comment: for some reason `.removeProp` wasn't working for me.So did `.prop('readonly', false)`.It is working now.thanks!

Comment: I know, I had to look it up too and fix it